# Reversing engineering snippet of assembly x86?

Tags: c, assembly, att

I am trying to convert this assembly code into a C snippet.

```
movl $0, -4(%ebp) # 4
movl -4(%ebp), %eax
sall $2, %eax
addl 8(%ebp), %eax
movl (%eax), %eax
cmpl 12(%ebp), %eax
jg .L6 

.L6:
nop
```

Here's what I have so far, but I think something is wrong. The line "movl (%eax), eax" confuses me in particular.

```
int local = 0;
if ((int*)((local << 2) + param1) > parameter2) {
   ; // do nothing
}
```

Comment: This is a little useless unless we see the entire context. There's probably some branch looping back into this code.

Comment: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation of `movl %(eax), %eax` is correct, but that of the line `addl  8(%ebp), %eax` is not. The correct code whould be something like this:

```
// parameter1 is an int* at 8(%ebp)
// parameter2 is an int at 12(%ebp)
int local = 0; // at -4(%ebp)
if (parameter1[local] > parameter2) {
   ; // nop
} else {
   // whatever is betwween jg and .L6
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but why is my interpreation of addl wrong? I thought that just says eax = eax + param2

Comment: param1, not param2. In your c code, you have "+ 2", which is wrong - it is "+ param1".

Comment: really appreciate the help but if you don't mind, could you explain why you know its parameter[local] instead of all of the stuff that I wrote?

Comment: `parameter1[local]` is, actually, exactly same as `*(int*)((local << 2) + parameter1)` (assuming that `parameter1` is e.g. an `int`). Your code is missing the initial * to dereference the pointer, and your initial code also had the literal number `2` instead of `param1`. Also, an array reference is more likely to be what was originally in the code, as you are reverse engineering here.